# I want to keep three div in one row of different width one in left one in center and one in right

Tags: css, html

I want to keep three div in one row of different width one in left one in center and one in right.

- Left div is of 160px
- Center Div is of 640px
- Right Div is of 160px

All i want is when they open in wide screen All will look separate on in left one in center one in right.

And When User Re-size Browser window or open in smaller resolution they come near to each other and do not collapse(means they acquire atleast 960px = 160 + 640 + 160)

As Far I done this with the help of StackOverflow & Google :

**Html :**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="leftDiv">left</div>
  <div id="centerDiv">center</div>
  <div id="rightDiv">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main div {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

#leftDiv
{
    width:160px;
}
}

#centerDiv {
    text-align:center;
    width:640px;
}

#rightDiv {
    text-align:right;
    width:160px;
}
```

If you can help me please provide me solution.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, by using this approach you have to reorder the elements as:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="leftDiv">left</div>
  <div id="rightDiv">right</div>
  <div id="centerDiv">center</div>
</div>
```

You could keep the `centerDiv` element at the center of the layout by using `auto` value for the left/right `margin`.

Also you could set a minimum width to the container element (`#main`) in order to prevent collapsing the layout.

```css
#main {
  min-width: 960px; /* minimum width: 160px + 640px + 160px */
}

#leftDiv  { float: left;  width:160px; }
#rightDiv { float: right; width:160px; }

#centerDiv {
  width:640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cepof/3/edit)**

Comment: It does not look to display the divs in one row!

Comment: @Reza Believe me, they **are** in one row. I've used `min-height` property for the middle column to distinguish the columns.

Answer (score 0):

For these i would suggest using twitter bootstrap, you just need to do this:
 
css:

```
#main {
   min-width:960px;
}

/* these are optional, but you do want your columns to scale unless you have a max width */

#leftDiv, #rightDiv {
   width: 160px;
}

#centerDiv {
   width: 640px; 
}
```

html:

```
<div id='main' class='row'>
     <div class='col-md-2' id='leftDiv'></div>
     <div class='col-md-8' id='centerDiv'></div>
     <div class='col-md-2' id='rightDiv'></div>
</div>
```